# Self signed certificate issue with WooCommerce rest api connection

Tags: ssl

I’ve got a simple php script which is connecting to my wordpress to create a product. Using the woocommerce rest api library.

```
$woocommerce = new Client(
  'https://dev.example.co.uk',
  '123456789',
  '123456789',
  [
      'wp_api' => true,
      'version' => 'wc/v3',
      'sslverify' => false,
  ]
);

// foreach item

$woocommerce->post( 'products', $data );
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException: cURL Error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in /srv/www/example.co.uk/current/web/app/themes/exampletheme/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php on line 417

I’ve attempted the following:
Get the certificate from the dev site:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.co.uk:443 | tee logfile
```

Copied the certificate and made a file from it called **certificate.crt**

```
MIICyTCCAbGgAwIBAgIJANB2....
```

Uploaded to:

```
/srv/www/example.co.uk/current/web/wp/certificate.crt
```

And now trying to use it to prevent this error.
**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'http_api_curl', function( $handle ) {
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, ABSPATH . 'certificate.crt');
});
```

// the value of ABSPATH is: /srv/www/example.co.uk/current/web/wp/

Same error remains. Can't tell if the custom cert is being used or not too. If it is then something else must be wrong maybe.

Comment: Do not consider my as an answer but have you tried the option to use Let's Encrypt (https://letsencrypt.org/) instead of a self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the ssl verification by using `'verify_ssl' => false`. So in your code you should change:

```
[
      'wp_api' => true,
      'version' => 'wc/v3',
      'sslverify' => false,
  ]
```

to:

```
 [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v3',
        'verify_ssl' => false,
    ]
```

Then you don't need to change any source code.

Answer (score 0):

@wharfdale I faced the same problem. All you need to do is to open the file vendor\automattic\woocommerce\src\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Options.php and look for function verifySsl() and replace true with false. The line in the function should look like this after change

return isset($this->options['verify_ssl']) ? (bool) $this->options['verify_ssl'] : false;

This option sets curl options for verifying SSL to false in the woocommerece library and it works!